# A Game Theory Puzzle

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I encountered this game theory puzzle that I have no idea how to solve.

> > In [image], two players take turn to fill in $1,\dots, 9$ in the circles (each number can only be used once). The player who can make one of the edges to have sum equals $20$ wins the game.

I haven't taken any game theory course, but I have read about Zermelo's theorem. As I believe, without strong reasons, that the game should have a winning strategy, I have tried to consider a case where the game ends in a draw and try to deduce backwards that at some point at least one of the players have made some suboptimal moves. And that if they choose to play optimally, it is possible to guarantee a win. However, since there are too many combinations, I have no idea how to show this generally.

Comment: First of all, you have to show that one of the players has a winning strategy. Since draws are possible, this is not obvious. Another question : Is the game over if one of the edges has sum $20$ ? I guess this is the case (If all circles are filled up, the opponent might be able to produce another sum $20$).

Comment: An alpha-beta-algorithm should clarify the situation. The number of possible games is very low (for computers).

Comment: @Peter Yes, the first player who gets an edge to have a sum equals $20$ wins. The game will be over once a player wins. I also think this should have a simple solution that doesn't require computer as it is posted as a fun puzzle/ challenge.

Comment: If it is known which player (if any) has a winning strategy, it might be easier to find how the player can win (or what both players have to do to draw).

Comment: Taking symmetry into consideration, there are only $18$ opening moves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Play 5 in a corner. When your opponent plays $a$, play $10-a$ in the symmetrical spot on the same edge.

Comment: OOps, I meant $10-a$. Will edit!

Comment: First player puts $5$ in a corner.  Second player puts $a=9$ in another corner.  If first player symmetrically puts $1=10-a$ in the third corner, this overlooks a winning move of $6$ between the $5$ and the $9$, leaving that winning play open for second player.

Comment: @hardmath, good point. I was interpeting the rules to mean an edge had to be filled in – all four slots – before you could claim victory. If you can claim victory after just three of the four places on an edge are filled in, then you're quite right, and we need to work harder to solve the game.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the answer, it is simple and clever.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am not sure about the rule as it doesn't specify. But if the second player puts down $x$ in another corner, the first player can just put down $15-x$ in the edge containing both $5$ and $x$, where $x$ is $6,7,8$ or $9$.

Comment: The following fix should work the alternative rules (there must be a better way of phrasing it though); "Play $5$ in a corner. When opponent plays $a$, play $10−a$ on the same edge but not in the corner unless it's the only option (for which you will win). If opponent plays $a$ in a corner then check if we have a win and if so play it (by computing the sum $s$ of each edge having free slots left and checking if $20-s$ is still availiable to play). If no immediate win is possible then play $10-a$ on the edge adjecent to $a$ but opposite to the edge connecting $a$ and $5$ and not in the corner."

Answer (score -1):

in this game the person, who puts the first value in circle can always win, but he has to make pair of 10 on each side on which the second user is putting a value.

always remember sum of 20 is never going to be calculated on the side having 5 in circle, and if the 5 is at edge then only sum of 20 can be achieved from its opposite side

Comment: You have made strong claims about the solution, but none of them are supported. Please demonstrate your working - your answer is nothing more than a guess otherwise.

Comment: @nij which one do u want me to prove

Comment: **Everything** needs to be proven, or at least referenced, if it is not either fundamental or trivial.